# Rails variable assigned in view, need advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, twitter-bootstrap, view

Need some advice, I know that it is a bad practice to assign variable directly in view. But I find only one way to realise bootstrap 'nav-tab'. May be there is another way? Thanks

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <% answer = [] %>  // Here it is..
    <% @questions.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
        <li class="<%= "active" if index == 0 %>">
          <a href="#pane<%= index + 1 %>" data-toggle="tab">
            <%= question.title %>
          </a>
        </li>
       <% answer << [index, question]%>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <% answer.each do |i, a| %>
      <div id="pane<%= i + 1 %>" class="tab-pane <%= 'active' if i == 0 %>">
        <div class="links">
          <%= link_to '', edit_question_path(a), class: "icon-pencil" %>
          <%= link_to '', a, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "icon-remove" %>
        </div>
        <%= raw a.content %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
</div><!-- /.tabbable -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build `answer` in the Controller, with:

```
@answer = []
@questions.each_with_index do |question, index|
  @answer << [index, question]
end
```

Then use `@answer` in the `<div class="tab-content">` section, instead of `answer`.

Or you could build the whole `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` section in the controller, since you're already looping through `@questions` to build `@answer` anyway:

```
@answer = []
@all_questions = ""
@questions.each_with_index do |question, index|
  @all_questions << "<li class=\"#{"active" if index == 0}\"><a href=\"#pane#{index + 1}\" data-toggle=\"tab\">#{question.name}</a></li>"
  @answer << [index, question]
end
```

Then change the `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` section in the view to:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <%= @all_questions %>
</ul>
```